# Hyperledger Fabric Deploy Chaincode Failed Using HFC SDK

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Hey guys Im using hyperledger v0.6 and I try to deploy my chaincode using the HFC SDK. Although I can successfully deploy my chaincode using CLI Interface it somehow does not work using HFC SDK. When trying to deploy I get the following error message:

error = {"error":{"code":2,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}}},"msg":"Error: sql: no rows in result set"}

This problem seems to be somehow related to this issue https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/64

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I noticed the problem occurs when I use the ``membersrvc`` name inside of the ``docker-compse.yaml`` file. When I replaced it with an actual ip adresse, e.g., ``172.17.0.2:7054``, the issue seemed to disappear. Before running ``docker-compose up`` again, I cleaned some things: ``rm -rf /tmp/keyValStore/`` and ``docker-compose rm membersrvc vp0``. The same in my application that used hfc: for gprc connections I switched (from using names membersrvc and vp0 or peer) to ip addresses with ports, e.g., ``chain.addPeer("grpc://172.17.0.3:7051");`` I realize it is a matter of a prop. docker config...

Answer (score 1):

I see you are v0.6.   Hyper ledger has released v1.0 which is a significant rewrite.  You won't be able to get support for v0.6... you should consider moving up versions.